# Electron App with Vue throwing Uncaught Error: ENOENT

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, vue-cli-3

I am creating an Electron App with Vue by using the plugin *vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder* with standard webpack config given by the electron-builder plugin.

After adding a dependency of [*kubernetes-client*](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client) and using it in the script as below :

```
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client
const kubeclient = new Client({ version: '1.13' })
```

gives the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT, renderer/specs/swagger-1.13.json.gz not found in <<path>>/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar
    at createError (electron/js2c/asar.js:126)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:603)
    at new Client (swagger-client.js?6d40:214)
    at eval (AppData.vue?749b:20)
    at Module../node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/AppData.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:7924)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:727)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (AppData.vue?a6b9:1)
    at Module../src/components/AppData.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:12875)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:727)
```

Seems like the Asar electron bundle created is not able to resolve some path which is used inside the *kubernetes-client* library (on which I have no control)
How do I solve the error ?

Comment: Try setting it to externals for webpack and see if you get the same error:  in your vue.config.js `builderOptions: { external: ['kubernetes-client']`

Comment: used `node: { __dirname: true }` in webpack config as per https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599#issuecomment-251241493. That issue is now gone but facing some other issue.